# Finding spectrum of a Kronecker factored + block-partitioned matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-factorization

I have dense $d\times d$ matrices $A$, $B$, $C$ with $d\approx 1000$ and want to find the top $10^5$ eigenvalues of the following positive definite matrix:

$$
\Sigma=
\left(\begin{matrix}
A\otimes A & C^T\otimes C\\
C\otimes C^T & B\otimes B
\end{matrix}\right)
$$

- Cheap: assume $C=0$ and compute $\lambda(A)$, $\lambda(B)$, since $\lambda$ [commutes](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/henry/reports/kronthesisschaecke04.pdf) with $\otimes$.
- Expensive: power method. Storing $10^5$ eigenvectors is 40 GB.

Is there something in between the two?

#### Motivation

$\Sigma$ is a

- covariance of $x\otimes x$, where $x$ is a partitioned Gaussian vector with mean 0 and
  $
  E[xx']=
  \left(\begin{matrix}
  A&C^T\\
  C&B
  \end{matrix}\right)
  $
- Gauss-Newton block for neural network linear layer if we assume forward/backward values are jointly Gaussian